# Starting IIS Express without admin rights

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, iis-express

we are trying to start IIS Express from unit-tests without admin rights...

We currently have the following:

- IIS Express is started from the unit-test via ProcessStartInfo, Process.Start and '/config' option in Arguments
- In our custom applicationhost.config, which is passed to Process.Start, via the Arguments, 'ProcessModel' tag is add to 'Clr4IntegratedAppPool' application pool, which is used in our site, with the 'loadeUserProfile = true', 'userName' and 'password' attributes, that are pointing to valid Windows user who belongs to 'Users' group

But this does not seem to work: when i query the used user in server code, name of the user is not the one that is given in applicationhost.config.

Any ideas?

Cheers

-kimmo

Answer (score 1):

IIS Express does not support full application pool feature. So your `processModel` settings in config file is ignored, and the process identity is just the account who launch the process.

Only some pool settings are honored, such as

- managedRuntimeVersion, the .NET Framework CLR version (2.0/4.0/none).
- managedPipelineMode, integrated or classic.
- a few others.

Comment: Do you know if we can do this by starting IIS Express via "run as?" I tried it but i got an error "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:23786"

Comment: @KiLa the difficulty is that whether that account you choose to "run as" must have enough permissions to launch the process and hook to HTTP API.

Comment: Ah, ok. Its a normal account that belongs to standard Windows 'Users' group